# Developing HTML website with fixed div's that clip on screen sides

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to develop web site with this layout:

[image]

My main goal is to make this site non-scrollable and to scale div's acording to screen size, so if I run it on pc in fullscreen and on TV in fullscreen I don't want it to be non-proportional.

I can't figure out how to get these div's clip to bottom/top/sides but still have this div in middle same size for every screen size.

These 4 div's that clip on sides and bottom/top should have width and height in percentages but this div that should be in middle should have 800x600px width/height.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem (please forgive me, if I'm too dumb). Why you don't simply set the size-attributes for your border elements with percentages (height: 80%;) and the size of your centered div to (width: 800px; height: 600px;).
If you want always the same gap left-div <-> center-div (and the others) the following should work:
left: 0;
width: auto;
margin-left: 40px; /* or whatever you want */

Comment: Nah, you're not dumb. My english is too bad so i can't express myself. I was trying to do that but i can't figure out how to clip those divs on top/botom/left/right.

Comment: Really be careful with the decision you are making. For most sites, it is not recommended to have a lay-out like that on a +Full HD resolution. The reader wants most of the content in the centre of the screen, not all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` to clip those divs on the sides of the screen, and just give them percentage width/height.

```
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  height: 10%;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 24%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  mergin-left: -400px
}
```

Note: I was just making estimations as to the values of the percentages used, but for the center div, its top and left margins should be negative of the half of the value of its height and width, respectively.

Comment: Thanks Arnelle, that's it. I have now something to start from. +1

Comment: Though this center div is not in center of the screen but i'll try to figure it out somehow. :)

Comment: @user2813059 yeah. I just assumed that it was in the center. but yes you can figure that out. good luck :)